# Want apply "Position" in my list of Entities

Tags: curated-data, properties

I want apply `"Position"` in my list of Entities:

```
Entity /@ GeoEntities[CountryData["Belarus"], "Lake" | "Canal"]["Position"]
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know how to add it right.
In that expression it works fine:

```
Entity["Canal", "AhinskiKanal::8w7vp"]["Position"]
```

Comment: Belated welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#["Position"]&/@GeoEntities[CountryData["Belarus"], "Lake" | "Canal"]
```

Comment: alternatively `Through[(GeoEntities[CountryData["Belarus"],"Lake"|"Canal"])["Position"]]`

Comment: @chuy, i  like that better. Perhaps, you can post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use one of my favorites [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html)to help:

```
Through[(GeoEntities[CountryData["Belarus"],"Lake"|"Canal"])["Position"]]
```

I find it particular useful when working with lists of Entity objects that you want values from.